# How to set same viewmodel to two views in fresh mvvm in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have two views Add and Edit view both views are different UI but same viewmodel. By using mvvm i have set binding context to both view as same viewmodel. I am new to fresh mvvm. In fresh mvvm, I don't know how to set same viewmodel to two views. Another one is, I have passing parameter to the viewmodel constructor, how it is possible in fresh mvvm. Please give your valuable suggestion.

[image: Exception thrown in root level page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the accompanying view would be inferred by the names. But for this use case, you should explicitly mention which view to use. There is a method for that, you should be able to use it like this:

```
// For adding
CoreMethods.PushPageModel<AddEditViewModel, AddView>();

// For editing
CoreMethods.PushPageModel<AddEditViewModel, EditView>();
```

Of course, taking into account the actual parameters that you still need to specify for the `PushPageModel` method. Also, I have assumed the names of your view model and views here, but I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: Please mention the "CoreMethods" assembly. CoreMethods is not supported.

Comment: `CoreMethods` is part of FreshMvvm. All your view models should inherit from `FreshBasePageModel` and you navigate to different pages by using `CoreMethods.PushPageModel<YourViewModel>()` instead of referencing actual pages because that would break the MVVM pattern

Comment: In view code behind, how will i call **CoreMethods.PushPageModel<YourVIewModel>()** instead of **BindingContext = new YourViewModel();**

Comment: Like I mentioned, you should not need to do that. FreshMvvm supports something that is called view model to view model navigation. Instead on creating new pages and setting the `BindingContext` manually, navigate to new pages by using `CoreMethods.PushPageModel<YourViewModel>()`

Comment: Have a look at this for example: http://michaelridland.com/xamarin/freshmvvm-n3-navigation-in-freshmvvm/

Comment: The root level throws the **Unhandled Exception**, I have attached the screenshot in my question. Please refer my updated code.

Comment: Please, try to understand how this works before using it. As mentioned in the exception method, the page `MainPage` is not found. When navigating like this you should always have a pair of view and view model which are named `MyView` and `MyViewModel`. It all works on how your objects are named. So in this case, it cannot find the accompanying `MainPage` for your `MainPageModel`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. It's now working fine.

Comment: Great, please accept this as an answer if it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in doing this for the first page you load in your app, such as a Splash screen, this might help -

```
Page page;
if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
{
    page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<SplashPageModel>();
}
else
{
    // We will load our phone only splash screen
    page = new SplashPagePhone();
    FreshPageModelResolver.BindingPageModel(null, page, new SplashPageModel(FreshIOC.Container.Resolve<DataService>()));
}

var navContainer = new FreshMvvm.FreshNavigationContainer(page)
{
    BarTextColor = Color.White
};
MainPage = navContainer;
```